# Как открыть файл с правами администратора?

Tags: c++, winapi

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "C:\\test.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Открывает без прав.

Comment: Вместо `"open"` использовать `"runas"`

Comment: @VTT не помогло.

Comment: Что значит "не помогло"? Это правильный способ

Comment: @VTT всё равно запускается без прав.

Comment: И нет диалога UAC, спрашивающего про запуск с привилегиями администратора?

Comment: @VTT у меня отключён UAC..

Comment: Ну если он отключен, то тогда процесс и так будет запущен с повышенными привилегиями.

Comment: @VTT http://prntscr.com/mcs02b это если запускать без прав,а с runas тоже самое

Comment: Это окошко говорит о том, что программа падает, а не о том, что она запущена без привилегий администратора.

Comment: @VTT ну она падает,если запускать без прав.

Comment: А как вы ее запускаете с правами?

Comment: @VTT http://prntscr.com/mcs5n7

Comment: Если стоит эта галочка, то программу нельзя будет запустить без привилегией. А как вы именно запускаете программу? Может ей аргументы нужны или что-то подобное?

Comment: @VTT если запускаю без помощи c++ он запускается.но если запускаю с помощью c++ она падает.

Comment: Так я и спрашиваю, как конкретно вы его запускаете, чтобы он не падал. С этой галочкой даже при использовании `"open"` процесс должен будет запускаться с привилегиями администратора.

Comment: в c++ хоть open,хоть runas,всё равно падает,а если вручную через пкм>запустить от имени админа или  с галочкой+даблклик всё работает.

Comment: А этому приложению при запуске не надо указывать рабочую папку или аргументы передавать?

Comment: @VTT не понял..